# Ingress linking when carrying multiple keys

Tags: ingress

So I've found it's good to store key copies in containers to make it easy to drop before hacking, to get more keys. I'm just worried that if I'm carrying 2 keys and I create a link both will be used. I believe this used to happen and I'm unsure if it's still the case.

Thanks

Comment: Having keys left over after linking is the primary purpose for having multiple keys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This does not happen. AFAIK this never happpened. One link consumes one key.

You also do not need to drop the container with the keys. Keeping keys in a container is sufficient to enable key hacking.

Comment: I did not know containers worked that way, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that happened very early on in closed beta, we definitely noticed it. Dropping the key before hacking seems to increase the chance of getting another copy, while having it in a container doesn't...

Comment: What do you mean, having the key in a container doesn't increase your chances of getting another? I hack additional keys with that method all the time. With the key not in a container your chance of getting another one is precisely zero.

Comment: I find if it's in a container you can get a copy, but you're much more likely to get a copy if it's dropped when you hack it. If I have a key in my inventory, either in a container or not, I almost never get a copy, it does happen, but very rarely. If I drop my copy, or a container with a load in it, I'm much more likely to get a copy. But thanks for your input, I'll try this tomorrow further :-)